# Unset remove only the first result of the php unset() method

Tags: php

Not sure if this is a dumb question but could not find anything mainly because I don't know how to phrase it.

I have an array

```
$array1 = array(apple, orange, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
```

if I do `unset(orange);` both entries will be unset (duh!) 
is there another function that will only remove one orange entry?? so I can get

```
$result = array(apple, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
```

**edit:** turns out the mistake was elsewhere thank you all for your help
am a begginer at SO, do I delete this question lock or what happens with it :D

Comment: `unset(orange)` makes no sense in the context of this example. Are you simply looking for `array_unique()`?

Comment: nop, `array_unique` wont remove orange if its the only one

Comment: No, it won't. So what's the logic? You want to remove exactly *one* orange?

Comment: if there are 2 oranges, I want to remove one, if there is one orange I want to remove that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array1 = array(apple, orange, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
$array2 = array(apple, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
$array3 = array(apple, apricot, melon, watermelon);

function unset_first_occ ($array, $val) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $val) {
            unset ($array[$key]);
            break;
        } 
    }
}

unset_first_occ (&$array1, 'orange');
unset_first_occ (&$array2, 'orange');
unset_first_occ (&$array3, 'orange');

var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
var_dump($array3);
```

Result :

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "orange"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "apricot"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "melon"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "watermelon"
}

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "apricot"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "melon"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "watermelon"
}

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "apricot"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "melon"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "watermelon"
}
```

Comment: looking at all the answers being the same, is there a chance my oranges to be 100% identical? to have the same id and value?? because I am doing this but both oranges are getting removed.

Comment: There is no reason for them to be "identical". I just used the EXACT same code you gave to declare the arrays, and it's working fine on my side. If you var_dump your array before trying to remove anything, does it display two oranges separatly ? If so, they're not considered as identical and unset by key should work no matter what.

Comment: Yes but this is an example the actual code is massive :). Basically the array is whatever item you chose to add to your cart. There is also the functionality to add 2xOranges at once, instead of clicking twice, which might result in a duplicate occurrence of oranges. I still need to see through the code I guess. Am the third developer to go through it..!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_search` to find the key of the FIRST occurence of orange, then use the key returned by `array_search` to unset it.

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'orange', '...'];
$indexOfOrange = array_search("orange", $fruits);
if (false !== $indexOfOrange) {
    unset($fruits[$indexOfOrange]);
}
```

Comment: totally true, I changed to code accordingly. Thanks

Comment: actually that is exactly what I am doing, `unset(orange)` meant to be  `unset(array[key])` but in my laziness I simplified it. But seeing your answer it just occurred to me though that I might not have two oranges in my array in the first place..!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unset[$array[1]);` to remove the particular element from the array.

Comment: That is what am doing but `orange` entries are 100% identical

Comment: or you can use `unset($array["orange"]);` so you do not have to remember the array position

Comment: @swiss_blade `orange` is not a key in this array, so that won't work.

Comment: You are right @deceze, I only typed half my thought! I also meant to say that in order to remove just 1 instance of "orange", alexandros has to use keys....

Answer (score 1):

No need to make it complex. IF you want to remove duplicate values from your array, use `array_unique`. See this.

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(apple, orange, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
    $result = array_unique($array1);
    print_r($result);

?>
```

If you want to remove the 'orange' from this array use this

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(apple, orange, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
    $key = array_search('orange', $array1); // $key 
    unset($array1[$key]); 
    print_r($array1);

?>
```

Comment: i do not want to remove duplicate entries

Comment: U just want to remove that orange??

Comment: I do not know the position of the orange before hand, also if I search the array for orange and get the position unset(array[orangePos]) for some reason unsets both entries.

Comment: I admire your persistence :P that is what I am doing but for some reason both oranges get removed. Either there is actually one orange and the rest of my code is wrong, or both entries are identical, i.e. have the same key and value